# Strain-Energy and Deflection function

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science

I am trying to understand how to derive the mechanical strain energy in an Euler-Bernoulli beam fixed between two torsional springs as shown in this paper: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0960-1317/17/9/016/meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An axial residual stress is going to tend to change the length of the beam. For a beam oriented along the $x$ axis with deflection $w(x)$, we can write the length at any one point in differential form as $$ds=\left\{\left(dx\right)^2+\left[dw(x)\right]^2\right\}^{1/2}=dx\left[1+\left(\frac{dw(x)}{dx}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}\approx dx\left[1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dw(x)}{dx}\right)^2\right]$$ where the approximation arises from a Taylor series expansion for small displacements.
   The corresponding axial strain in this differential element is $\epsilon=\frac{ds-dx}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dw(x)}{dx}\right)^2$. Multiply this strain by the constant residual stress to obtain the work done per unit volume and then integrate over the beam volume to obtain
   $$U_\mathrm{residual\;stress}=\int_0^L \sigma_0\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dw(x)}{dx}\right)^2\right] hb\,dx$$ where $hb$ is the cross-sectional area.
2. For bending, we have a stress that generally varies across the cross section as well as down the length of the beam. The differential strain energy density per unit volume is $\sigma\,d\epsilon$. Assume linear elasticity of an isotropic material (so that $\sigma=E\epsilon$, where $E$ is Young's modulus) and integrate $E\epsilon\,d\epsilon$ with respect to the strain to obtain $\frac{E\epsilon^2}{2}$, which is also known as the strain energy density or elastic energy density. This density applies to any arbitrary differential element; therefore, let's write $dU=\left(\frac{E\epsilon^2}{2}\right)dV$ to represent the differential strain energy.  Now [approximate the curvature as $w(x)^{\prime\prime}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Strain_in_an_Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam) to obtain a strain of $\epsilon\approx -w(x)^{\prime\prime}y$ for a distance of $y$ from the neutral axis.
   Integrating over the beam volume, we note that the moment of inertia $I$ is defined as $\int\int_A y^2 dA$; thus, we pull that part out, leaving only the integration over the beam length: $$U_\mathrm{bending}=\int_0^L EI\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{d^2w(x)}{dx^2}\right)^2\right]dx$$
3. The beam is supported on both sides by a spring, whose torsional stiffness (or resisting moment per angular displacement $\theta$) is derived elsewhere in the paper as $k=4EI_a/L_a$. The elastic energy is therefore $\frac{1}{2}k\theta^2$ or $\frac{1}{2}k\left[dw(0)/dx\right]^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}k\left[dw(L)/dx\right]^2$ for the left and right spring, respectively. Because $w(0)=w(L)$ by symmetry, the total spring energy is $$U_\mathrm{spring}=\frac{4EI_a}{L_a}\left(\frac{dw(L)}{dx}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your great and detailed response ! I understand most of it, I just have a view questions:


1. Can you show me how you get $dU=\left(\frac{E\epsilon^2}{2}\right)dV$  ? 

I replace $\sigma$ by $E\epsilon$ and I get: $E \epsilon d\epsilon$ ... but now I don't see how to get to your result. 

2. Do you understand why to choose $w(L)$ instead of $w(0)$ for the spring energy ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure; I edited my answer to clarify. The first point is just an integration from 0 to the final strain (we would strictly use a dummy variable in the integrand for the strain variable). For the second point: $w(0)$ and $w(L)$ are equal, so you could use either. The authors chose the second.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear ! Great answers ! :)) By the way: I don't know, but did you try to compute the spring constant as provided in the paper $k=M/\theta$ ? When I use their moment and their angle definitions, the fraction immediately reduces to the spring constant obtained when $I_a = I$. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I have now done it a couple of times with Mathematica and I never get the long expression for $k$ which they propose when $I_a \isnot I$. So if you are interested, let me know what answer you get. :) Anyway, thanks a lot !